# python: checking if a string of integers is greater than zero isn't working when the string contains more than one zeros

Tags: python

I have a function that needs to validate a pin which is passed to it as a string. The pin cannot be a negative number, it cannot have letters, it cannot be all zeros, no special characters and it has to be 4 or 6 digits in length. Here's the function that I've written for this:

```
def validate_pin(pin):
    valid = False
    if str.isdigit(pin):
        if int(pin) > 0 and len(pin) == 4 or len(pin) == 6:
            valid = True
    return valid
```

The function is working perfectly except for when the string is all zeros like "000000" but I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). `or` has a lower precedence than `and`, so `valid` is set to `True` if the `len(pin) == 6`, regardles of what happens in the first part of the conditional.

The code basically says:

```
if (int(pin) > 0 and len(pin) == 4) or len(pin) == 6:
```

But you meant:

```
if int(pin) > 0 and (len(pin) == 4 or len(pin) == 6):
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

Your condition is wrong:

```py
... len("000000") == 6:
```

yields *True*, and therefore (because the *or* in front of it) your whole *if* expression will evaluate to *True*.

Change your function to:

```py
def validate_pin(pin):
    return (len(pin) in (4, 6)) and pin.isdigit() and (int(pin) > 0)  # Parentheses for clarity only
```

Answer (score 1):

here

```
def validate_pin(pin):
    valid = False
    if str.isdigit(pin):
        if int(pin) >= 0 and len(pin) == 4 or len(pin) == 6:
            valid = True
    return valid
```